# convert nodejs buffer to Uint16Array

Tags: node.js, buffer, typed-arrays

I would like to convert a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to Uint16Array

I tried:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from([0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x12, 0x34])
const arr = new Uint16Array(buffer)
console.log(arr)
```

I expect `[0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0100, 0x1234]`

but I get `[0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x12, 0x34]`

how can I convert buffer to 16 bits array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take in account [byteOffset](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_byteoffset) buffer property because

> When setting byteOffset in Buffer.from(ArrayBuffer, byteOffset,
> length), or ***sometimes when allocating a Buffer smaller than
> Buffer.poolSize***, the buffer does not start from a zero offset on the
> underlying ArrayBuffer

You should also take care of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

```
let buffer = Buffer.from([0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x12, 0x34])
buffer.swap16()   // change endianness
let arr = new Uint16Array(buffer.buffer,buffer.byteOffset,buffer.length/2)
console.log(arr)
console.log([0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0100, 0x1234])
```

output:

```
> console.log(arr)
Uint16Array(4) [ 1, 2, 256, 4660 ]
> console.log([0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0100, 0x1234])
[ 1, 2, 256, 4660 ]
```

Same !

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks! However what happens when you get a byte offset error: `start offset of Uint16Array should be a multiple of 2`. My buffer has a  buffer.byteOffset of 7