# Nodejs Uint8Array,Uint16Array, Uint32Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I'm trying to figure out how to work with the buffer's representation in int.
Simple code

```
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(4, 'a');
var interface16 = new Uint16Array(buffer);
var interface8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
console.log(interface16);
console.log(interface8);
```

Why does the log output the same arrays (by value and length)? After all, I'm doing a data representation in the form of 1 and 2 bytes per integer. At least the manuals say that Uint8Array - takes 1 byte from the buffer, which I think of as a sequence of 0s and 1s, in this case 32 ( 4 * 8). That is, I can put up with the fact that it will be an array with 4 elements.
But Uint16Array takes 2 bytes for an integer, that is, the number must be different and the size of the array is 2.
What am I wrong about and which buffer to pass to these constructors in order to visually see the difference?
I suspect that in any case the returned array will be the same length as the number of bytes, or that it is a matter of how the console generates output. Probably. But there is not enough knowledge to understand why.
Thank you for your attention.

P.S. If you also advise some non-brain-exploding literature directly on this issue, it will be great.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-typedarrays

Comment: A nodejs `Buffer` is, despite the name, not an `ArrayBuffer` but an `Uint8Array` subclass. To access its underlying buffer (and construct the typed array as a view on it), you need to write `new Uint16Array(buffer.buffer);` and `new Uint8Array(buffer.buffer);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, both typed arrays end up having 4 elements, but the `Uint8Array` only uses 4 bytes to represent its contents, while the `Uint8Array` uses 8. You can see this by inspecting the [`byteLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteLength) property:

```js
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(4, 'a');
var interface16 = new Uint16Array(buffer);
var interface8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
console.log('Uint16 length: %d', interface16.length);
console.log('Uint16 byteLength: %d', interface16.byteLength);
console.log('Uint8 length: %d', interface8.length);
console.log('Uint8 byteLength: %d', interface8.byteLength);
```

**Output**

```
Uint16 length: 4
Uint16 byteLength: 8
Uint8 length: 4
Uint8 byteLength: 4
```

So the typed array constructors are creating typed arrays with the same number of **elements** as the source buffer, but the `Uint16Array` constructor is using two bytes instead of one for each element, filling the high-order byte of each element with zero.

Answer (score 0):

first you create a buffer with 4 a's inside.

then you you call this function with the buffer :

the doc says : `new Uint16Array(object);`
When called with an object argument, a new typed array is created as if by the TypedArray.from() method.

see more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from

it creates an array of 4 uint16 by using every bytes of the buffer

a = 0x61 = 97
you then get four 97.

here is a stackoverflow of a sucessful buffer to uint16 conversion
[convert nodejs buffer to Uint16Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996221/convert-nodejs-buffer-to-uint16array)